# How to get notified when a new file is uploaded to a webpage?

Tags: http, website, webpage

I want to know whenever there is new file uploaded to a site https://some.site.com/en/folder/page.html#tab=this-tab

specifically this url on that page: https://some.site.com/en/folder//pdf/SomePDF.pdf

visually nothing changes apart from size of the file on that page.

Visualping works only if some text changes on that site. But sometimes the size can be same to the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

A [HTTP HEAD](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) request will simply return metadata about the resource you requested, including the [Content-Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2) which you indicated changes whenever a new version is uploaded, and when that fails hopefully the server will return a meaningful [Last-Modified](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.2) header too.

This is not a regular web browser task though, but can be performed using command line tools like [curl](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1685/send-an-http-head-request-wcurl), or once-off via the debugging windows in browsers like [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor).